# How do I transform my SQL query to a MongoDB query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, transform

I migrated timeseries data from SQL to MongoDB. I'll give you an example:

Let's say we have a measurement device with an ID, where once per minute a value gets read. So per day, we have 24 hours * 60 minutes = 1440 values for that device.

In SQL, we have 1440 single rows for this device per day:

```
ID          Timestamp                Value
400001       01.01.2017 00:00:00      ...
""           01.01.2017 00:01:00      ...
""                  ...               ...
""           01.01.2017 23:59:00      ...
```

I migrated the data to MongoDB where I now have one document per day, with the values distributed to 24 hour array that respectively contain 60 minute fields containing the values (and only one Timestamp with the date XX-XX-XXXX 00:00:00):

`{ ID: 400001,
  Timestamp: 01.01.2017 00:00:00,
  Hours: 
       [ 0: [0: ..., 1: ..., 2: ..., ....... 59: ... ], 
         1: [0: ..., 1: ..., 2: ..., ....... 59: ... ],
          .
          .
        23: [0: ..., 1: ..., 2: ..., ....... 59: ... ]
       ]
}`

My Problem is:
I want to transform the following SQL statement to mongoDB:

```
SELECT (Val) AS Val, (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(ArrivalTime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00'))) * 1000 AS timestmp FROM database WHERE ID = 400001 AND ArrivalTime BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1470002400) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1475272800) ORDER BY ArrivalTime ASC
```

Output
[image]

Since in MongoDB I only save the day Timestamp and then split the values in arrays, I don't have a Timestamp for each Value like in SQL. So if I want to for example, get the values between 01.01.2017 02:14:00 and 01.01.2017 18:38:00, how would I do that?

I made a MongoDB query that can give me the Values between two whole days:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([{$match: {ID: '400001', $and: [ {Timestamp_day: {$gte: new ISODate("2016-08-01 00:00:00.000Z")}}, {Timestamp_day: {$lte: new ISODate("2016-10-01 00:00:00.000Z")}}]}},{$unwind:"$Hours"}, {$unwind:"$Hours"}, {$group: {_id: '$Timestamp_day', Value: {$push: "$Hours"}}}, {$sort: {_id: 1}}]);
```

Output
[image]

But I need it like in SQL that I can also just give out the Values for a few hours, and with the correct Timestamp given per each Values.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Given your new data structure, query that gives out the whole day is no longer the same as query that would give out a set hours of the day. This is the same as if you suddenly decided to store dates, hours and minutes in different columns in SQL - you wouldn't be able to use the initial query anymore. You have to use different query (or queries) here just the same.

Comment: Can you post some sample data? From just skipping through your question, I have a feeling you could solve that by using $slice: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/

Comment: I don't know how $slice should help me.. there is an article where it's said, that you can use mapReduce for exactly my case. Sadly, there is no example given for it:

Comment: http://blog.maisnamraju.com/2017/03/03/map-reduce-in-mongodb.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "ID": '400001',
        "Timestamp_day": {
            $gte: new ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            $lte: new ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$Hours",
      includeArrayIndex: "Hour"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$Hours",
      includeArrayIndex: "Minute"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "_id": 0, // remove the "_id" field
        "Val": "$Hours", // rename "Hours" to "Val"
        "Timestamp": { // "resolve" our timestamp...
            $add: // ...by adding
            [
                { $multiply: [ "$Hour", 60 * 60 * 1000 ] }, // ...the number of hours in milliseconds
                { $multiply: [ "$Minute", 60 * 1000 ] }, // ...plus the number of minutes in milliseconds
                "$Timestamp_day", // to the "Timestamp_day" value
            ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        "Timestamp": 1 // oh well, sort by timestamp ascending
    }
}]);
```

With an input document of

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0e7d096216d24dd605cdec"),
    "ID" : "400001",
    "Timestamp_day" : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "Hours" : [ 
        [ 
            0.0, 
            0.1, 
            2.0
        ], 
        [ 
            1.0, 
            1.1, 
            2.1
        ], 
        [ 
            2.0, 
            2.1, 
            2.2
        ]
    ]
}
```

the results look like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "Val" : 0.0,
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "Val" : 0.1,
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:01:00.000Z")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "Val" : 2.0,
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:02:00.000Z")
}

/* 4 */
{
    "Val" : 1.0,
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-01T01:00:00.000Z")
}

/* 5 */
{
    "Val" : 1.1,
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-01T01:01:00.000Z")
}

/* 6 */
{
    "Val" : 2.1,
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-01T01:02:00.000Z")
}

/* 7 */
{
    "Val" : 2.0,
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-01T02:00:00.000Z")
}

/* 8 */
{
    "Val" : 2.1,
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-01T02:01:00.000Z")
}

/* 9 */
{
    "Val" : 2.2,
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-01T02:02:00.000Z")
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comment you need to calculate the difference between any value and its respective preceding value. This can be done the following way - there might be nicer ways of achieving the same thing, though... The first part is almost identical to the solution above except it has an added $match stage to remove null values as per your specification.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "ID": '400001',
        "Timestamp_day": {
            $gte: new ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            $lte: new ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$Hours",
      includeArrayIndex: "Hour"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$Hours",
      includeArrayIndex: "Minute"
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "Hours": { $ne: null } // get rid of all null values
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "_id": 0, // remove the "_id" field
        "Val": "$Hours", // rename "Hours" to "Val"
        "Timestamp": { // "resolve" our timestamp...
            $add: // ...by adding
            [
                { $multiply: [ "$Hour", 60 * 60 * 1000 ] }, // ...the number of hours in milliseconds
                { $multiply: [ "$Minute", 60 * 1000 ] }, // ...plus the number of minutes in milliseconds
                "$Timestamp_day", // to the "Timestamp_day" value
            ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        "Timestamp": 1 // oh well, sort by timestamp ascending
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": null, // throw all documents in the same aggregated document
        "Docs": {
            $push: "$$ROOT" // and store our documents in an array
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: "$Docs", // we flatten the "values" array
        includeArrayIndex: "Docs.Index", // this will give us the index of every element - there might be more elegant solutions using $map and $let...
    }
}, {
    $group: { // YES, unfortunately a second time... but this time we have the array index for each element
        "_id": null, // throw all documents in the same aggregated document
        "Docs": {
            $push: "$Docs" // and store our documents in an array
        }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        "Docs": {
            $let: {
                vars: { "shiftedArray": { $concatArrays: [ [ null ], "$Docs.Val" ] } }, // shift value array by one to the right and put a null object at the start
                in: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$Docs",
                        as: "d",
                        in: {
                            "Timestamp" : "$$d.Timestamp",
                            "Val": { $ifNull: [ { $abs: { $subtract: [ "$$d.Val", { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$shiftedArray", "$$d.Index" ] } ] } }, 0 ] }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$Docs"
}, {
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$Docs"
    }
}]);
```

The results using your sample data set look like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "Val" : 0.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:01:00.000Z"),
    "Val" : 0.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:02:00.000Z"),
    "Val" : 2.0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:04:00.000Z"),
    "Val" : 3.0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:05:00.000Z"),
    "Val" : 0.0
}

/* 6 */
{
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:06:00.000Z"),
    "Val" : 1.0
}
```

Comment: You're my hero. Thank you!

Comment: Jederzeit gerne zu Diensten, @wuestenloewe! ;)

Comment: Wenn du wüsstest wie lange ich daran schon rumprobiere. Hatte vorläufig eine Lösung mit mapreduce, aber die Performance war grauenhaft. Hast mir richtig weitergeholfen :)

Comment: Könntest du mal einen Blick auf die "Antwort" werfen die ich weiter unten im Post verfasst habe? War leider etwas zu lang für einen Kommentar und ich bräuchte nochmal deine Hilfe. Wäre echt super

Answer (score 0):

Eventuell könntest du mir nochmal helfen, auch ein Tipp würde reichen @dnickless.. Ich bräuchte eine Query die mir den Betrag der Differenz zum vorherig gemessenen Wert gibt (in einem bestimmten Zeitraum, zu einer bestimmten ID).

Also als Beispiel: 
    `Timestamp_day: ISODate("2017-01-01T01:00:00.000Z"),
     Hours: [
               [ 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, null, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, ... ],
               [ ... ],
                 ...
             ]`

Und dann als output:

```
{
  'Timestamp' : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
  'Val' : 0.0 /* nix - 1.0 */
}

{
  'Timestamp' : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:01:00.000Z"),
  'Val' : 0.0 /* 1.0 - 1.0 */
}

{
  'Timestamp' : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:02:00.000Z"),
  'Val' : 2.0 /* 1.0 -  -1.0 */
}

{
  'Timestamp' : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:04:00.000Z"),
  'Val' : 3.0 /* -1.0 - (null) - 2.0 */
}

{
  'Timestamp' : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:05:00.000Z"),
  'Val' : 0.0 /* 2.0 - 2.0 */
}

{
  'Timestamp' : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:06:00.000Z"),
  'Val' : 1.0 /* 2.0 - 3.0 */
}
```

Hoffe es ist einigermaßen verständlich was ich meine

Comment: Hast Du mein Update gesehen? Funktioniert es so?

Comment: Ich bekomme leider einen error, da man den $substract operator nicht auf strings anwenden kann

Comment: soweit ich weiß kann ich den typ nicht verändern oder? müsste also wenn dann direkt meine values als double speichern

Comment: ich ändere mal meine db dass die values als double gespeichert werden (macht eh um einiges mehr sinn) und probiere das skript dann aus. gebe dir dann ein update :)

Comment: funktioniert super. vielen dank für deine hilfe!